# Maximum number of sockets in an extension lead

Tags: power-supply

In a UK extension lead, what are the maximum number of sockets that you can get?

Comment: Do you want this migrated to DIY? not really on topic for SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a massive amount of sockets, you should go for a rack-cabinett PDU.

Example, this one: Which is 20way

[image]

Google for "PDU UK 20 way" to find retailers.